# OSGi service class dependencies

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I was wondering what would be a good way of organising my bundles so that classes required as parameters to services can be shared between them.

I have a couple of services interfaces which expose class types which will need to be referenced between bundes e.g.:

```
public interface DoesThis {
   public CustomClassB doSomething(CustomClassA customClassA);
}
```

From my understanding `CustomClassA` (if defined in the same bundle as the exposed service) would not be available to other bundles so would it be best to expose classes references between bundles in a package which is then exported?

Just as a sub question: Are services and package exports supposed to work hand-in-hand... It wasn't clear from the documentation I was reading if this was the case?

Thanks

Comment: Could you fix your code example to make it clear what you're asking? That isn't valid Java.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yes. All types referenced by the interface must be in an exported package. There are a few options:

- They could be in the same package as the interface, in which case they will naturally be exported at the same time as the interface, because in OSGi we always export/import whole packages.
- They could be in a different package but exported by the same bundle as the service interface.
- They could be in a different package and exported by a different bundle. In this case the service interface bundle must import that package.

If you think about it, it doesn't make sense for the types not to be exported. For example, how could a consumer call your `doSomething` method if it cannot create an object of type `CustomClassA` to pass in, or if it cannot understand the return type `CustomClassB`?

Regarding your sub question... yes, package exports exist principally to support the service registry. Services can only work if the provider and the consumer can come to an agreement on the "contract" of the service, which in Java terms means they load the same interface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I think this is what I expected. Just as a follow-up, In order to reference the service in another bundle would I create a compile time dependency (I'm using Maven) on my bundle which exposes the service? (i.e. how do I reference the service class if it's in another bundle?). I understand that the context will allow me to get hold of concrete implementations however I need a reference to the Interface/Service in order to compile my second bundle!  Thanks again

Comment: No, you import the package that contains the *interface*. The whole point of services is to decouple you from the specific implementation class, so you only depend on the interface. In order to obtain the service object, it's easiest to do this with Declarative Services. For example try the [Bndtools tutorial](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks again... I understand the the interface concept, I'm struggling to find a way to resolve build time dependencies as I'm using Netbeans which doesn't seem to be as mature as Eclipse for OSGi. The only way I've found to do this in Netbeans is to add a project dependency which, I'd assume, will allow me to reference any classes in the whole project which is not what should happen (if Netbeans was OSGi aware). For just now it will have to do as I have to use Netbeans as part of a corporate policy!

Comment: I think it's still possible to achieve: you can have the interface(s) in one project and the implementations in another project that depends on the first. Anyway you have my sympathy for your company forcing you to use an inferior IDE... I don't understand why companies insist on policies that deliberately destroy the productivity of their developers!